# How to track mix panel time event with properties?

Tags: ios, swift, mixpanel

I am using mix panel and want to track that how long user spent time in some page. I know that this can be achieved by `Mixpanel.sharedInstance().timeEvent(eventName)` and to stop tracking time of that event code is `Mixpanel.sharedInstance().track(eventName)` , now mix p panel suggest that pass as many properties as possible in just one mix panel call. I want to do that when user leaves a page and I stop taking that duration event at that time I use method `Mixpanel.sharedInstance().track(eventName)` , so I want to pass properties also in that event , is it good approach to pass properties with stop duration tracking event? Will that work as expected? Or I need to track properties separately? Suggest me some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this, `Mixpanel.sharedInstance().track(name, properties: arrProperties)` handles both stop tracking duration of page and also track properties .